Shopify App Proxy, injecting meta-title, meta-description and og tags
I'm developing a Shopify App with App Proxy. In my backend generated html, which is working fine, I also add:
{% layout 'theme.liquid' %}
{% assign page_title = "A title" %}
{% assign page_description = "A nice description" %}
{% assign page_image = "My CDN image url" %}
{% assign image_url = "My CDN image url" %}

When deployed and rendered by the Shopify Shop, If inspect the generated page meta tags, I see that page_title and page_description are correctly placed into meta title and meta description, BUT page_image/image_url aren't rendered in og:image, ecc. They don't appear anywhere in the DOM. Same for og:title and og:description.
I also checked some themes, and they believe like this:
{%- if page_image -%}
<meta property="og:image" content="http:{{ page_image | image_url }}">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https:{{ page_image | image_url }}">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="{{ page_image.width }}">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="{{ page_image.height }}">
{%- endif -%}

and
<meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ shop.name }}">
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ og_url }}">
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ og_title | escape }}">
<meta property="og:type" content="{{ og_type }}">
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ og_description | escape }}">

What am I doing wrong?
